# beer by the six-pack -- why "BY THE six-pack"?

Tags: prepositions

Source: [C++ For Dummies, 7th Edition](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-111882377X.html) by Stephen R. Davis (2014)

Example:

> The numbers we’ve been familiar with from the time we could first count on our
>   fingers are known as decimal numbers because they’re based on the number 10.
>   (If beer **by the six-pack** had been invented early enough, our number system
>   might well be based on the number 6.) In general, the programmer expresses
>   C++ variables as decimal numbers. Thus you could specify the value of var as
>   (say) 123, but consider the implications.

Almost sounds like the name of a company. The whole thing **by the six-pack** is confusing to me.

Comment: Based on the questions you've been asking lately, I'm starting to think that *C++ For Dummies* is a really bad book for an ESL speaker to read - it's full of quirky usage and slangy writing that really has nothing to do with the main topic.  Either that, or it's a really *good* book for an ESL speaker, since it will expose you to a lot of informal writing!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*By* is the preposition we use to designate the pragmatically indivisible "units" we count, measure or price with.

We can count **by** twos: 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 . . .  or **by** threes: 3, 6, 9, 12 . . . or tens: 10, 20, 30, 40.

Likewise, in the US we buy and sell eggs **by** the dozen—it used to be you couldn't buy eggs except in cartons of 12, although now half-dozen cartons are available. We buy and sell fabric **by** the running yard, wood **by** the board foot, meat **by** the pound, cigarettes **by** the pack of 20 or carton of ten packs. We buy and sell milk **by** the half-pint or pint or quart or half-gallon or gallon, Coke **by** the 12-oz or 2-liter bottle, carryout whiskey **by** the fifth or quart, or **by** the shot if consumed on the premises, and  carryout beer mostly **by** the sixpack.

Answer (score 1):

In case it's the six-pack part that's causing confusion:

Beer is commonly sold in packs of six cans or bottles.  We call these six-packs.

[image: Six-pack of bottles]
[image: Six-pack of cans]